# Xamarin forms with mvc architecture

Tags: xamarin

In Xamarin Froms
is there any more cleaner way to make applications rather than using 2way data binding, MVVM?

I tried to use it but, it that kind of workflow really doesn't fits me.
and couldn't find any other smart ways to do it.

if yes, then how should I implement the MVC architecture?

or in xamarin ios or android would mvc workflow work?

something not like this
in XAML file

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Salary, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always just access you view from your codebehind and set values there.
Just think of the Codebehind as your controller, and bam, welcome to MVC world.

Assume you have some Xaml like this (MainPage.xaml):

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" />
```

In the codebehind (aka the MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
this.MyLabel.Text = "Hello world!"
```

The main reason to go with MVVM is Databinding. Once you got how it works, it helps you having much cleaner UI Code and the effort learning it is propably worth it, as the whole Xamarin.Forms framework is designed specifically for it.

Comment: haha. thanks but just to be clear.  what if theres a list and i want to create, initialize and put it in the list view?? how would that work like?? + if you say so. think wont be bad to give it a try

Comment: `var list = new ListView() { /* set some properties here */ }; this.Add(list);` It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: actually i was wondering how i could add an view(in MVC) in list.  some like this. <<<  list.Add(new PostView("uploader", "content", image))   >>>

Comment: I think that's a hole different question on its own. But: Never try to work against the framework. If you have to use inconvenient hacks to achieve your goal, you are probably not using the right tool for you.

Comment: hmm.. but that't what actually MVC is. i just wanted a clear example... Well it still helped alot for me! thanks!